# Jasper Reports : variables referencing other variables?

Tags: jasper-reports, order-of-execution

Inside a Jasper report, I'd like to have something with two non-cumulative variables (computed for each record) :

**var_age** : a calculation of age based upon elements of the current record.

**var_sanitized_age** : something that takes `var_age` and changes its value if needed

So far it seems to me that I can't control in which order these variables will be computed. And that this could have `var_sanitized_age` either use `var_age`'s previous value, or fail.

Is there a way to have Jasper correctly compute one variable, with an expression that uses the values of one or several other variables ?

And as a natural extension to this question, could I define a cumulative variable named **var_sanitized_age_average** that would reliably average upon one of the variable's latest value ?

Comment: Variables are normally computed in the order in which they are declared in the report/dataset.  Does the problem you describe occur when `var_age` is declared before `var_santized_age`?

Comment: No indeed it doesn't. But I wasn't sure if it was just by chance in this specific context, or whether the "computed in order" rule was always applicable. If you write this into a regular answer, I'll accept it as the valid one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are computed in the order in which they are declared in the report/dataset.

Therefore if `var_sanitized_age` depends on `var_age`, you need to be declare  `var_sanitized_age` after `var_age`.

Computing the average of `var_sanitized_age` as `var_sanitized_age_average` would also work as long as the variables are declared in this order.